# use cloudblobclient to get reference to 2 or more containers

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

There are a bunch of mixed answers from SO on reusing `cloudblobclient` across requests.

Now say I decide to go with 1 `cloudblobclient` per request, can I use the client to get reference to more than 1 containers in 1 method?

in code:

```
var thumbC =  cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(thumbContainer);

var thumbBlockBlob = thumbC.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

await thumbnailBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(thumbStream);

var largeC =  cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(largeContainer);

var largeBlockBlob = largeC.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

await largeBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(largeStream);
```

where `cloudBlobClient` is injected via `services.AddScoped`.

Comment: Have you tried it? It works on my side without problem.

Answer (score 0):

You code is correct.

In your code:

```
  [var thumbC =  cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(thumbContainer);]


  [var thumbBlockBlob = thumbC.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);]


  [var largeC =  cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(largeContainer);]


  [var largeBlockBlob = largeC.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);]
```

These four lines of code didn't send request to Azure Storage and just create instance of related class. So these lines of code works anyway.

If you what to get reference to more than 1 containers in 1 method to ensure that you can get the containers without any error, I suggest you follow the code below.

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<CloudBlobContainer> blobContainers = cloudBlobClient.ListContainers().Where(blobContainer => blobContainer.Name == "thumbContainer" || blobContainer.Name == "largeContainer").ToList<CloudBlobContainer>();
if (blobContainers.Count != 2)
{
      throw new Exception("containers are not exist");
}
else
{
      //.....
}
```

More information for your reference:

[Cloud​Blob​Client.​List​Containers(String, ContainerListingDetails, BlobRequestOptions, OperationContext)  Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.listcontainers?view=azure-dotnet)